# Cascade delete happening even after foreign keys disabled

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

There is a foreign key constraint with on delete cascade in MS SQL server.

For maintenance purposes, we want to delete records in the primary key table P without deleting records in foreign key table F.

So, disabled the foreign key as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE F NOCHECK CONSTRAINT constraint_name
```

Verified that the foreign key is disabled with the statement

```
select * from sys.foreign_keys where is_disabled=1 and name=constraint_name
```

When I run,

```
delete from P
```

, records in F also get deleted even though foreign key constraint is disabled. I tried in Postgres and Oracle and am unable to reproduce this behavior.

How do I delete records without cascade deleting?

Comment: Perhaps someone should revisit past decisions to understand why you implemented a cascading FK while duplicating that logic in a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, we also had to execute:

DISABLE TRIGGER ALL ON F

Comment: Unless this is an answer to the question, please remove it and edit it into your question.